# Oracle: Joining two table with a common column plus a additional column(latest effective date) from second table to select other column

Tags: oracle, oracle11g, oracle-sqldeveloper

Joining two table with a common column plus an additional column (latest effective date) from the second table to select another column. I joined the tables with all conditions, but the resulting table has duplicate records as there are multiple records in Table2 for the same identifier, out of which I just need the record with the latest effective date. I am using Oracle.

Table1 (Column A, B, C, D);
Table2 (C, Efft_date, X),
Table3...

The result should be as below after Joining the tables: A, B, C, X and columns from other tables

Value of X depends on latest/max value of efft_date from Table2.

Other Info: There are other tables that are joined and other conditions in where clause.

Please help to join the tables without duplicates

Answer (score 0):

So you need to further restrict your result set based on the max of `table2.efft_date`. So you need a clause like:

```
AND table2.efft_date = ( SELECT MAX( table2b.efft_date) 
                           FROM table2 AS table2b
                          WHERE table2b.c = table2.c )
```

This assumes that table2 cannot have duplicate `efft_date` values.

Comment: I tried this, however getting following error "ORA-01799: a column may not be outer-joined to a subquery"  And YES there is no duplicates efft_date values.

Comment: It sounds like you're putting it in the `ON` clause in the join. This is a where predicate and goes in the `WHERE` clause.

Answer (score 0):

You need to join to a subquery so that you get just 1 "latest date" for each value of column c. For this I recommend using `row_number()`

```
select t1.A, t1.B, t1.C, t1.D, t2.x, t2.efft_date
from table1 t1
inner join (
     select c, x, efft_date, row_number() over(partition by c order by efft_date DESC) as rn
     from table2
     ) t2 on t1.c = t2.c and t2.rn = 1
...
```

Note that by ordering the dates in descending values, the most recent date will be assigned the row number of 1. Hence the join condition `and rn = 1` will only allow the most recent dates to be included in the result.

Changing the order to ascending date order would do the revers, just allow the earliest dates.